# Spring boot YML properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml, properties-file

I have a "**spring boot**" application which uses "**application.yml**" file for externalized properties in my application.
Following is a small portion of my YML:

```
    direction:
      threshold: 2
      head: From {1} head {0}
      turn: Turn {0} 
      straight: Continue {0}
      elevator.A: Choose floor {0} 
      elevator.E: Take elevator to floor {0}
      elevator.W: Take elevator to floor {0}
      destination: Arrive at {0}
```

I looked at various ways of getting the properties into my spring application. Most of them point me to create a bean as follows

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="direction")
public class ApplicationConfig {
     public String threshold;
     public String head;
     ........
}
```

then declare all the individual properties as variables and add getter setter.

Before I switched to SpringBoot and YML, I had used **PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer** which had a method called 
**processProperties** where I could process all properties and put them in a Map and then access the map in the application to get individual values. The draw back of this method though was I had to declare a **PropertyManager** in XML like this.

```
<bean class="org.bii.xyz.util.PropertyManager">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>/res/xyz.properties</value>
            <value>/res/environment.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I want to avoid using context XML files.

Is there any way I can use something similar to ProcessProperties with YML files without using a context xml file?

So far all my searches have lead me to creating a bean and declaring indvidual properties or accessing the properties file using SEPL **${...}**

Comment: Add a [`YamlPropertiesFactoryBean`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/YamlPropertiesFactoryBean.html) to have your yaml file converted to a properties object.

Comment: in my pom.xml, I added `<dependency>
   <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
  </dependency>`